# Mostrar imagen en lugar del path

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una tabla con 4 inputs mas un input tipo file, lo que quiero hacer es que al darle al botón me añada los datos... eso hace, los añade, pero al momento de elegir una imagen solo me pone la ruta donde esa img aparece, no me pone la imagen en si a lo mejor alguien sabe si estoy haciendo mal algo o que? capaz esta no es la forma y la estoy haciendo mal o no sé!!!

```
function cargarDatos(){

    //obtener los datos que ingresó el usuario
    let image = document.querySelector("#image").value;
    let title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
    let descripcion = document.querySelector("#descripcion").value;
    let ubicacion = document.querySelector("#ubicacion").value;
    let precio = document.querySelector("#precio").value;

    //obtener el elemento tabla
    let tabla = document.querySelector("#tabla");

    //crear el contenido de la tabla
    let cuerpoTabla = `
    <tr>
        <td>${image}</td>
        <td>${title}</td>
        <td>${descripcion}</td>           
        <td>${ubicacion}</td>
        <td>${precio}</td>
        <br>
    </tr>`
    ;      

    tabla.innerHTML += cuerpoTabla;
}

function crearTabla(){
    const tabla = document.createElement("table");
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    const cabezal = document.createElement("thead")
    for(let i = 0; 1 < 4; i++){
        const th = document.createElement("th");
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                th.innerText = "image"
                break;
                case 1:
                th.innerText = "title"
                break;
                case 2:
                th.innerText = "descripcion"
                break;
                case 3:
                th.innerText = "ubicacion"
                break;
                case 4:
                th.innerText = "precio"
                break;
                default:
                break;
        }

        thead.appendChild(th);
    }
    tr.appendChild(thead);
    tabla.appendChild(tr);
    document.body.appendChild(tabla);
}

crearTabla();



<form action="">
      <label for="image"></label>
      <input type="file" id="image" accept="image/*">
      <br><br>
      <label for="title">Título</label>
      <input type="text" id="title">
      <br>
      <label for="descripcion">Descripción</label>
      <input type="text"id="descripcion">
      <br>
      <label for="ubicacion">Ubicación</label>
      <input type="text" id="ubicacion">
      <br>
      <label for="precio">Precio</label>
      <input type="text" id="precio">
  </form>
  <br>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="cargar" onclick="cargarDatos()">Añadir</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <thead>
              <th>Imagen</th>
              <th>Título</th>
              <th>Descripción</th>
              <th>Ubicación</th>
              <th>Precio</th>    
          </thead>
      </tr>
      <tbody id="tabla">
  
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: ya intentaste usar la api web? https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Léete [ask] y paséate por el [tour] para aprender a realizar buenas preguntas (con buenos títulos!) y aprender cómo funciona este sitio, y de paso te regalan una medalla!!  Respecto a tu pregunta, no tengo claro lo que pretendes. ¿mostrar una previsualización de la imágen al agregar una fila de datos en la tabla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tan solo quieres mostrar la imagen sin subirla, esto es lo que andas buscando creo.

Realiza estos cambios dentro de la función `cargarDatos()`:

1. Comenta o elimina esta línea:

```
let image = document.querySelector("#image").value;
```

pues vamos a necesitar ese nombre `image` para referirnos al id del input que estás usando el tipo `file` más adelante.

2. Agrega este trozo de código en dicha función:

```
  const [file] = image.files
  if (file) {
    img = `<img src="` + URL.createObjectURL(file) + `" width="150px;">`
  } else {
    img = 'Sin imagen'
  }
```

que básicamente lo que hace es definir una constante denominada `file` que contiene el objeto de la imagen seleccionada en el input.  El condicional siguiente verifica si está bien asignada, y en cuyo caso definimos una nueva variable `img` que va a contener el elemento `<img>` que apuntará correctamente a la imagen seleccionada gracias al método [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).  Si no está bien asignada (es decir, no se selecciona ninguna imagen) asignamos la cadena de texto `Sin imagen`  a la variable `img`.

3. Y por último, modificamos esta línea:

```
<td>${image}</td>
```

por esta:

```
<td>${img}</td>
```

para realizar correctamente la sustitución.

A continuación dejo un snippet funcional (pulsa Ejecutar para ver cómo funciona):

```js
function cargarDatos() {

  //obtener los datos que ingresó el usuario
  // let image = document.querySelector("#image").value;
  let title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
  let descripcion = document.querySelector("#descripcion").value;
  let ubicacion = document.querySelector("#ubicacion").value;
  let precio = document.querySelector("#precio").value;

  //obtener el elemento tabla
  let tabla = document.querySelector("#tabla");

  const [file] = image.files
  if (file) {
    img = `<img src="` + URL.createObjectURL(file) + `" width="150px;">`
  } else {
    img = 'Sin imagen'
  }

  //crear el contenido de la tabla
  let cuerpoTabla = `
    <tr>
        <td>${img}</td>
        <td>${title}</td>
        <td>${descripcion}</td>           
        <td>${ubicacion}</td>
        <td>${precio}</td>
        <br>
    </tr>`;

  tabla.innerHTML += cuerpoTabla;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label for="image"></label>
  <input type="file" id="image" accept="image/*">
  <br><br>
  <label for="title">Título</label>
  <input type="text" id="title">
  <br>
  <label for="descripcion">Descripción</label>
  <input type="text" id="descripcion">
  <br>
  <label for="ubicacion">Ubicación</label>
  <input type="text" id="ubicacion">
  <br>
  <label for="precio">Precio</label>
  <input type="text" id="precio">
</form>
<br>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="cargar" onclick="cargarDatos()">Añadir</button>
<br>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <thead>
      <th>Imagen</th>
      <th>Título</th>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Ubicación</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </thead>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="tabla">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Listo, me anduvo..

Comment: Gracias @masterguru !!

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro :-) Si esta respuesta es válida para tu pregunta deberias marcarla como Aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y no quede eternamente pendiente. Mírate este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar respuestas, y ya de paso, al ser nuevo en este sitio, invierte dos minutos en realizar el [tour] y aprender su funcionamiento básico, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas llamando al value de la imagen y eso te va a traer un fakepath y no muestra nada, entonces se me ocurre que cargues la imagen de forma oculta con un evento y luego le pases el src de la imagen en cargarDatos, quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function cargarDatos(){

    //obtener los datos que ingresó el usuario
    //let image = document.querySelector("#image").value;
    let title = document.querySelector("#title").value;
    let descripcion = document.querySelector("#descripcion").value;
    let ubicacion = document.querySelector("#ubicacion").value;
    let precio = document.querySelector("#precio").value;
    let image = document.getElementById('imgOculta');

    //obtener el elemento tabla
    let tabla = document.querySelector("#tabla");

    //crear el contenido de la tabla
    let cuerpoTabla = `
    <tr>
        <td><img width="50" src='${image.src}'></td>
        <td>${title}</td>
        <td>${descripcion}</td>           
        <td>${ubicacion}</td>
        <td>${precio}</td>
        <br>
    </tr>`
    ;      

    tabla.innerHTML += cuerpoTabla;
}

function crearTabla(){
    const tabla = document.createElement("table");
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    const cabezal = document.createElement("thead")
    for(let i = 0; 1 < 4; i++){
        const th = document.createElement("th");
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                th.innerText = "image"
                break;
                case 1:
                th.innerText = "title"
                break;
                case 2:
                th.innerText = "descripcion"
                break;
                case 3:
                th.innerText = "ubicacion"
                break;
                case 4:
                th.innerText = "precio"
                break;
                default:
                break;
        }

        thead.appendChild(th);
    }
    tr.appendChild(thead);
    tabla.appendChild(tr);
    document.body.appendChild(tabla);
}

var cargaImgOculta = function(event) {
    var imagen = document.getElementById('imgOculta');
    imagen.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};


crearTabla();
</script>


<form action="">
      <label for="image"></label>
      <input type="file" id="image" accept="image/*" onchange="cargaImgOculta(event)">
      <img id="imgOculta" width="0" />
      <br><br>
      <label for="title">Título</label>
      <input type="text" id="title">
      <br>
      <label for="descripcion">Descripción</label>
      <input type="text"id="descripcion">
      <br>
      <label for="ubicacion">Ubicación</label>
      <input type="text" id="ubicacion">
      <br>
      <label for="precio">Precio</label>
      <input type="text" id="precio">
  </form>
  <br>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="cargar" onclick="cargarDatos()">Añadir</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <table>
      <tr>
          <thead>
              <th>Imagen</th>
              <th>Título</th>
              <th>Descripción</th>
              <th>Ubicación</th>
              <th>Precio</th>    
          </thead>
      </tr>
      <tbody id="tabla">
  
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

con esto ya puedes generar la tabla y te mostrar las imágenes y datos que vienen del input